# python gtk.entry() icon connect: is it possible?

Tags: python, gtk, gtk2

I'm using in Pygtk 2.7 a gtk.Entry. I have set an Icon on this, I would like to know if it's possible to connect the icon to a fonction.
My construction is like this:

```
    def info(self, a, b):
        print "INFOS & HELP"
    def __init__(self):
        window = gtk.window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        #[...]     
        self.champ_adr_canal = gtk.Entry()
        self.champ_adr_canal.connect("activate", self.download, self.champ_adr_canal)
        self.champ_adr_canal.set_text("")
        boite_adr.pack_start(self.champ_adr_canal, False, True, 0)
        self.champ_adr_canal.set_icon_from_stock(1, gtk.STOCK_DIALOG_QUESTION) # the icon is here
        ### this line is a pseudo code ####
        self.champ_adr_canal.connect("clicked", self.info, "bouton info") # how can I do this? 
        ###                            ####
        self.champ_adr_canal.show()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkentry.html), you need to make the icon [activatable](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkentry.html#method-gtkentry--set-icon-activatable) and connect to the [`icon-press`](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkentry.html#signal-gtkentry--icon-press) or [`icon-release`](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkentry.html#signal-gtkentry--icon-release) signal:

```
self.champ_adr_canal.set_icon_activatable(1, True)
self.champ_adr_canal.connect("icon-release", self.info)
```